# Do I have to create a pepk and jks file for every single app bundle I generate in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle, app-bundle

Do I have to create a private key and jks file for every app bundle I generate in android studio? I noticed that I can't place them in another folder once I have created the private key and jks file and that it becomes confusing when I have more than a couple of app bundles created.

Comment: No, you can use a single key to sign multiple different bundles.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: You should be able to select a keystore and a key when you sign your app bundle: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing